# R plot properties in plotly

Tags: r, plot, plotly, r-plotly

I am trying to use the nice plotly charting engine in R. I have encountered several problems for which I am looking for solutions.
I want to use several properties from the base R `par`/ `plot`/`png` commands. What I would like to do in plots when I save them as png is:

```
png(...,width=5000,height=2750, res=500)
```

How would a corresponding code look in plotly (either by using the `png` function or by using `plotly_IMAGE()`)?

Then I would like to make the legend to have multiple columns instead of one column and multiple rows. I saw in a forum that this question has been asked and back then the programmer said this would come later. So what I want to do is something like

```
legend(...ncol=5)
```

in base R.

Finally I am struggling with the legend when I save the plot as png. No matter how the legend is formatted in the chart itself, in the png it always appears at the default location in plotly which is `x=1.02` and `y=1`. So what I would like is to see the legend being put in the png at e.g. `x=0.5` and `y=1`.

For the creation of the chart, I use the normal plotly function `plot_ly`. A sample code of the chart would be

```
 p <- plot_ly(test, x = date, y = ts, line=list(width=lwd, color=hblue),group= colnames(data_ts)[1], showlegend=legend, name=Names[1], fill=fill1)%>%
  layout(showlegend = TRUE,
         yaxis=list(title=ylab, size=0.02, color=hblue, type=log_mode, ticks="outside",linewidth=1,
                    tickfont=list(color=hblue, size=0.05), ticksuffix=perc_suffix,gridcolor=hblue,gridwith=0.75),
         xaxis=list(title=xlab, size=0.02, color=hblue, tickfont=list(color=hblue, size=0.55),
                    linewidth=1,linecolor=hblue,ticks="outside",gridcolor=hblue,gridwith=0.5),
         font=list(family="Arial", color=hblue),
         margin=list(l=60,r=30,t=30,b=40),
         hidesources=T,
         geo=list(showframe=T, framecolor=hblue)
         )
```

I am using the most recent version of plotly and R and the latest Java version. Thx for help.

Answer (score 1):

For any questions, Plotly now has a user guide on CRAN which you can download here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plotly/plotly.pdf

1. To use the plotly image function, it's on page 14, e.g.:

   ```
   p <- plot_ly(x = 1:10)
   Png <- plotly_IMAGE(p, out_file = "plotly-test-image.png")
   ```
2. As far as I know, there is still no way of making the legend have multiple columns but this resource should tell you how to modify the legend: https://plot.ly/r/legend/